# jquery slideDown position not ontop of content

Tags: jquery, slidedown

on the following test website:
http://gruebe-neu.marknolan.ch/#section-3

under the section 3 there is a timeline slider.
its a pdf archive. when you hover over the timeline file icon, jquery slideDown kicks in should present an overlay. but no matter what z-index or positioning i try, i can't get the slideDown be ontop of the other content.

i'm not sure its a matter of z-index - might be an overflow issue?

the elements are boxed in as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>Text / Icon <div>Overlay Content</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using latest Chrome and it's works properly (slideDown is on top).

Comment: really? i just opened up chrome. i can only see the top of the overlay. (tiny 2-3px yellow line)

Comment: 5 minutes ago it was fine, now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `caroufredsel_wrapper` (inline-css). The slideDowns start 2px above the bottom of `caroufredsel_wrapper`, so you see only 2px of the slideDown. If you remove the `overflow: hidden;`, also the content what is under the bottom of the wrapper will be visible.

If the inline css is generated from some js and you don't want to change it, you can also put this in your css file:

`.caroufredsel_wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}`

Comment: thanks that did it for the carousel. i'll give the thumbs up to you.

Comment: i just had another problem with the underlying div aswell. i changed it to overflow visible but with no luck... any ideas here?

Comment: ah - the !important part was missing aswell... all good thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the height of your outer div container (.caroufredsel_wrapper)
- increase the height and everything should work as expected :-)